# Laravel Livewire upload image using Media Library package

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-medialibrary

I am trying to fing how we can integrate `Livewire` with `spatie/laravel-medialibrary` in `Laravel`. In this code I can get the image information when user submit the form, but I can't save an uploaded image with `spatie/laravel-medialibrary`:

```php
class ProfileComponent extends Component
{
    use WithFileUploads;

    public $photo;

//...

public function submit()
{
    $this->validate($this->rules);

    $user = User::find(auth()->user()->id);

    $user->name = $this->name;
    $user->family = $this->family;
    $success = $user->save();


    //...
    try {
        $user
            ->addMedia($this->photo)
            ->toMediaCollection(User::MEDIA_COLLECTION_NAME);
    } catch (FileDoesNotExist | FileIsTooBig $e) {
        dd($this->photo);
    }
}
```

or I try to use this code, but I get an error too

```php
->addMediaFromDisk('/livewire-tmp/'.$this->photo->getFilename())
```

here we don't have `request` and by default `livewire` used `store` function for uploading images. how can we integrate them?

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
$user->addMedia($this->photo->getRealPath())->toMediaCollection('Colle');
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: @amin550 this code doesn't work correctly `File not found at path`